# Meteor stuck at building for web.browser (Windows)

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

[image]

My team mate uploaded a meteor project where he created it with mac. I cloned the project and tried to first do npm install followed by typing meteor. However, the project keeps getting stuck at Building for web browser. I searched many solutions online but am still unable to solve the issue. I am using a windows computer and apparently the problem is faced by windows users.

Please try to clone this project from https://github.com/sohskd/meteorProject and follow the instructions in the README to see if you encounter the same issue as me. Any advice to solve this issue will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Sometimes a `meteor reset` will help

Comment: Tried already. Still stuck at building for web.browser

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cd <project_folder>
rm -rf node_modules
meteor npm install
```

Comment: Hey man thanks however it is still not working. Removed the node_modules and tried "meteor npm install". Still stuck at building for web.browser

Comment: @Desmond Could you try to create empty meteor project to run it?

Comment: I created an empty meteor project and it can run. Only i cant run with this. It seems to be the problem with some js files inside?

Comment: Well, it shouldn't have such effect. You could try to comment all meteor packages in `.meteor/packages` file and run, then uncomment them one by one, trying to run the app every time. This way you could find the culprit.